# Map fragment filling almost all the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout

I am trying to share the height of my screen's layout between a `MapFragment` and a simple `TextView`, in such a way that the small `TextView` at the bottom of the screen takes all the space it needs, while the `GoogleMap` fragment fills the rest of the available screen.

like this:

[image]

The only problem is that I was only able to obtain such result by statically specifying the fragment's `android:layout_height` at `450dp`, and I haven't found a way to do so dynamically, so that the layout would adapt both its `landscape` mode and to mobiles with different screen sizes.

This is what I've tried to do:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" tools:context="madapps.bicitourbo.DetailsFragmentTwo">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">
        <!--android:paddingRight="16dp"-->
        <!--android:paddingLeft="16dp"-->

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mapFrag"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/headerTitle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Partenza da: Piazza Santo Stefano"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeBig" android:textColor="@color/textLightBlack"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and this is the unwanted outcome:

[image]

Comment: It sounds as though you would be best suited using a `RelativeLayout`.  Assigning the `TextView` to the bottom of the screen and the map above it and below the tabs that you have near the top.  Then the `TextView` should expand as needed upward and the map would adjust.

Comment: Why is everything wrapped in a ScrollView? :|

Comment: your comments solved it, thank you. the `android:layout_weight` attribute wasn't working only because of the `ScrollView` tag... probably you should leave an answer for me to accept ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments to my question solved it.

The `android:layout_weight` attribute wasn't working only because putting a `ScrollView` as the root tag blocks its effects.
By putting a `RelativeLayout` as root tag the weigth attribute works, and the TextView should expand as needed upward while the map would adjust.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent" tools:context="madapps.bicitourbo.DetailsFragmentTwo">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <!--android:paddingRight="16dp"-->
    <!--android:paddingLeft="16dp"-->

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapFrag"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/headerTitle"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Partenza da: Piazza Santo Stefano"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeBig" android:textColor="@color/textLightBlack"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `android:weightSum` gives the `LinearLayout` a total weight of 10.

So the `fragment` gets 9/10 of the LinearLayout, and the `TextView` gets 1/10 of the layout.

Comment: Why did you specify two attributes `android:layout_weight=9` and `android:layout_weight=1` for the fragment?

Comment: Because they each have their own weight. One is for the fragment and one is for the TextView.

Comment: I mean the same fragment View. It's not possible to put two times the same attribute for the same View.

Comment: what do you mean two times the same attribute?

Comment: check your fragment attributes... you've put two times the attribute `android:layout_weight`

Comment: ...yes because the TextView and fragment are separate. The TextView gets 10% of the LinearLayout, the fragment gets 90%

Comment: You have put two times the same attribute in the same View, this makes it three total times: 2 in the fragment, 1 in the textview

Comment: Your answer is not working, because there of the `ScrollView` tag blocking the `LinarLayout` `android:layout_weight` attribute from doing its job.

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice that. Why is that there in the first place?

Comment: just some leftover code from a different former layout

Answer (score 0):

you can use `RelativeLayout` for this

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="madapps.bicitourbo.DetailsFragmentTwo">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--android:paddingRight="16dp"-->
        <!--android:paddingLeft="16dp"-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Partenza da: Piazza Santo Stefano"
            android:textColor="@color/textLightBlack"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeBig" />

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mapFrag"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/headerTitle" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```